# Android Studio skipping some tasks while running clean Project

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, android-espresso

I am beginning to write some instrumentation test cases using Espresso framework. I have included the necessary dependencies in the `build.gradle` file. I have also set testInstrumentationRunner.

```
     dependencies {
      //Some more dependencies
     androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
     androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
     androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2' 
     }

    defaultConfig {
      minSdkVersion 14
      targetSdkVersion 23
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
      testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   }
```

After building the project, I can see all the relevant jars in `$module/build/intermediates/exploded-aar` folder. But Android Studio is not able to recognize the files related to Espresso in the test files.

[image]

I have tried the following things so far.

- Sync Project in Android Studio
- Clean Project
- Make module
- Restart Android studio

But none of them solves my problem. On Gradle console, I saw the Android studio is skipping all the tasks related to Android Tests.

```
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest SKIPPED
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript SKIPPED
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig SKIPPED
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets SKIPPED
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources SKIPPED
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources SKIPPED
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources SKIPPED
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources SKIPPED
```

But I have not written any specific gradle code to skip these tasks. So why are these tasks being skipped even after clean build? If somehow these tasks don't get skipped, then Android Studio will be able to recognize these files.

Comment: did you set `testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"`??

Comment: yes... I will update the build.gradle

Comment: https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/setup/

Comment: What about this line @IntelliJAmiya? I have gone through this link to do the initial set up.

Comment: @thedarkpassenger you miss: `compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'`

Comment: `clean project`, then `rebuild project`.. If it won't work `>File->InvalidateCaches/Restart-> Invalidate/restart`

Comment: @piotrek1543: yes, it is not added in the build.gradle file. But it is coming as a transitive dependency.

Comment: @thedarkpassenger did you cleaned, rebuilt and invalidated?

Comment: @piotrek1543: tried, clean project, then rebuild project and invalidate and restart.